# options_for_select in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

The options_for_select form helper in Rails builds a drop-down list collection with a pre-selected value like this:

```
<%= options_for_select([['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2], ...], 2) %>
```

What's the equivalent in HAML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lose the enclosing `<% %>` and just leave the `=`?

```
<%= whatever %>
```

becomes

```
= whatever
```

Just note the indentation is correct, of course.